# NSInvalidArgumentException when calling new view Controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder, segue

In an iOS app, under Interface Builder, I have my main View Controller with a navigation bar and a right navigation bar button.

I link this button to a second View Controller (buy right clicking and dragging), so that when I click on it, the 2nd View controller gets displayed.

However I always get the following crash when clicking:
`-[SecondViewController setMessages:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdf6482c880`

I tried to link the button to an IBAction function, and to open the second view controller via performSegueWithIdentifier, and the same issue happens once this function is called.

I tried to create a new destination view controller, and again same issue, which makes me think that something is wrong with my first view controller.
In another View Controller, I have exactly the same configuration and it works fine.

Anything corrupt with my first view controller ?

Comment: The error is telling you that whatever VC type the second one has, it doesn't have a function called `setMessages`, so either you didn't set the class type in Interface Builder for the second view controller, or your second view controller class doesn't have that function.

Comment: That was it, thanks !!!